# How to correct or amend mistake on form 8829

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction, amended-tax-return

I have a question regarding how to correct a mistake I made on my 2020 taxes on form 8829 regarding business use of my home.

For line 38 for the value of land for my home, I indicated $0 instead of the actual value. I use HR Block software and when I imported my 2019 taxes to start my 2020, it seems that the land value didn't import properly leading to being $0 on the form 8829. This mistake caused the allowable depreciation amount for my home to be greater than what it should have been.

How can I go about correcting this issue? I'm not sure if it's relevant but my business profit wasn't large enough in 2020 for my home deduction to actually be taken so the incorrect amount was marked as excess depreciation on line 44. So correcting this amount won't really change my overall 2020 taxes but it will affect what I can deduct in 2021 (or later) since that incorrect amount can be carried forward.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Since your body (only) says HRBlock: open your existing return, click "take me to", a few lines before the end of the Federal section click "amended return 1040X", and follow the instructions. I don't know if you'll be able to e-file though; I couldn't when I (much like you) tried in Feb to amend 2020. It didn't say e-file was prohibited (and I know the *IRS* system now accepts efile 1040X for 2019 or later where the original was efiled) or there was any specific error, but just that it wasn't accepted, until I gave up and did paper.

I'd expect any other software has a comparable, though perhaps not identical, capability. If not using software (or a preparer), of course you have to do it yourself.